# Copy to Clipboard Functionality in Javascript/PhoneGap Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, copy, clipboard

I simply want to copy some plain text into Clipboard but unable to do so. Here is my function:

```
function CopyToClipboard()
{
    CopiedTxt = "My Text";
    CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Can someone please guide me how to achieve this simple objective in JS?

===EDIT====
Thanks Bhavesh,

I have tried this and created the following functions:

```
function CopyOnSuccess()
{
    alert(4);
    showWait("Link copied to clipboard",1000);
    return;
}

function CopyOnError()
{
    alert(3);
    showWait("Failed to copy link to clipboard",1000);
    return;
}

function CopyToClipboard()
{
    alert(1);
    cordova.plugins.clipboard.copy(gCopyText, CopyOnSuccess(), CopyOnError());
    alert(2);
    return;
}
```

When I call CopyToClipboard It doesn't go beyond alert(1). Any idea what I am doing wrong. Of course I have successfully installed the plugin first.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with plain JS.

Comment: Really :-(
Then what is the easiest way? I do not want text selection etc. Just want the App to copy some text into Clipboard. It has to be cross platform. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement cordova clipboard plugin. It is based on what phonegap version you are using.

One of the link is given here please check it out.

https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard